# Datetime elapsed

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this quote:

```
var deadline=System.DateTime.Now;
deadline = new System.DateTime(deadline.Year, deadline.Month, deadline.Day, deadline.Hour+4, deadline.Minute, 0);
```

And I would like to transform it with a workday system.

The current input is 2022-02-15 14:25:00.000

The output is: 2022-02-15 18:25:00.000

A regular workday would be weekdays 08:00-16:00
So right now the output is elapsed by 02:25, and I would like to add for the next workday.

New output: 2022-02-16 10:25:00.000

I am not sure what condition should I need and how could I skip weekends too at once.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2):

There are several steps here.

First, although I *assume* your input is going to logically be inside a working day, I would not just add 4 to the hours. On the off chance that `DateTime.Now` returns a value that is closer to midnight than those 4 hours, it would throw an exception.

And if you want your solution to be general, as in you would be able to say "the deadline is 30 hours from now, only counting working hours", it wouldn't be able to work at all, even within a working day.

So, with that in mind, here's my proposal, expressed as pseudo-code

```
left (TimeSpan) = 4 # can be changed to whatever
timestamp = DateTime.Now

while left > 0
    if timestamp > end of working day OR not even a working day at all
    then:
        set timestamp to start of next working day
    else:
        calculate remainder = how much is left of current working day from "timestamp"
        if less than left
        then:
            add left to timestamp
            return timestamp as deadline
        else:
            subtract remainder from left
            set timestamp to start of next working day
```

Here is C# code that should accomplish this.

Some of the pieces are missing error handling, and can probably be optimized a lot.

```
void Main()
{
    var start = new DateTime(2022, 2, 21, 11, 34, 0);
    var deadline = GetDeadline(start, TimeSpan.FromHours(30));

    Console.WriteLine($"{start} + 30h in working hours = {deadline}");
}

public static DateTime GetDeadline(DateTime timestamp, TimeSpan timeUntilDeadline)
{
    if (timeUntilDeadline <= TimeSpan.Zero)
        return timestamp;
        
    (DateTime start, DateTime end) nextWorkingDay;

    while (timeUntilDeadline > TimeSpan.Zero)
    {
        var workingDay = GetWorkingDay(timestamp.Date);
        if (!workingDay.HasValue || timestamp >= workingDay.Value.end)
        {
            nextWorkingDay = GetNextWorkingDay(timestamp.Date);
            timestamp = nextWorkingDay.start;
            continue;
        }

        if (timestamp < workingDay.Value.start)
            timestamp = workingDay.Value.start;

        var remainder = workingDay.Value.end - timestamp;
        if (remainder > timeUntilDeadline)
            remainder = timeUntilDeadline;
            
        timestamp += remainder;
        timeUntilDeadline -= remainder;
    }

    return timestamp;
}

public static (DateTime start, DateTime end)? GetWorkingDay(DateTime date)
{
    // todo: handle holidays and vacations?
    switch (date.DayOfWeek)
    {
        case DayOfWeek.Monday:
        case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
        case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
        case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
        case DayOfWeek.Friday:
            return (date + TimeSpan.FromHours(8), date + TimeSpan.FromHours(16));
            
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

public static (DateTime start, DateTime end) GetNextWorkingDay(DateTime date)
{
    while (true)
    {
        date = date.AddDays(1);
        var workingDay = GetWorkingDay(date);
        if (workingDay.HasValue)
            return workingDay.Value;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
21.02.2022 11:34:00 + 30h in working hours = 25.02.2022 09:34:00
```

The output is due to:

1. The start timestamp is Tuesday, 11:34
2. 30 hours, only counting working days would first fill out Tuesday, consuming 4:26, giving us 25:34 left to process
3. Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, all consume 8 hours each, reducing the processing value down to 1:34
4. On Monday 25th, the deadline is thus 09:34

Corner-cases considered in the code:

1. If your starting-time is on a day without working hours (Saturday, Sunday), the next working day start is used instead
2. If your starting-time is after the end of a working-day (18:00 on a Monday for instance), the start of the next working day is again used
3. If your starting-time is before the start of a working-day (06:00 on a Monday for instance), the start of that working day is used
4. You can easily enhance the "get the working hours for this date" method to handle such things as holidays, vacations, or even non-typical days with, say, only 4 hours work, or late shifts, or whatever.